# Google Analytic tracking code doesn't work

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I just start to work with Google API. At first I upload a simple HTML file to a host that have a button to send some information to Google and I see correct result but when I test this method on my real project it doesn't work properly. I did same work as my simple sample put tracking code after < head >  tag

`<script type="text/javascript" >`

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];

_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-26*****-2']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function() {
 var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async =        true;
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
function sent_report(){
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','label','Over','back']);
}

</script >
```

and call

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','button','click','Just for test']);
```

but it doesn't make any change in my feedback in Google and its hard to debug because Google update feeds after 24h

Did I forgot some thing to do?or did something wrong?
Is there any problem that I run local host and didn't upload it to the host?!?!?
Thank you...

Comment: provide a link to your website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Analytics won't work on `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` or any other IP address. It needs a [FQDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name) to work correctly.

I usually setup www.example.com on my hosts file to redirect to `127.0.0.1` and I use that instead to test my code.

You can debug if you're coding is working or not by using [HTTPFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/httpfox/) and checking the requests to __utm.gif. The data you send is encoded as query parameters but it should be easy to read them.